# how to display data after parsing to UI

Tags: html, parsing, angular7

[image][image]

this is my first time to use parsing and angular7, I want to display the data in the front-end but I can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

this is the correct ansewer after a hard work

[image]